# EntityFramework SqlQuery ToList()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Why am I getting this error on this query?  I have used this format in other projects without an issue.

```
    var history = db.Database.SqlQuery<ReferralHistory>("dbo.GetReferralHistory @quoteGuid, @username",
        new SqlParameter("@quoteGuid", quoteGuid),
        new SqlParameter("@userName", userName))
        .ToList();
```

It doesn't like the ToList().

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error CS1061  'DbRawSqlQuery' does not contain a
>   definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'DbRawSqlQuery' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I just want the results of a stored procedure to fill a List<> of this object type, which matches the output results of the stored procedure.

Comment: Do you have `ToListAsync()`?

Comment: You have '@username' in your query and you add '@userName' as your paramenter. Is that just a typo in your question or in your code as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say that you are definitely missing the System.Linq namespace. Creating a simple test application and including System.Linq

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<Class1>("storedproc_test @foo", new SqlParameter("@foo", foo) ).ToList();
```

compiles fine. Removing System.Linq gives the error you are getting.

Comment: That was it.  I had it it in all in all my other classes but somehow missed it in this one.  Thanks.

Comment: This is correct answer. Faced same issue today. It was fixed.